How do I make JetBrains Rider put tests project in the main solution folder?
I have recently moved from VS to Rider, and I can't figure this out. I am trying to create unit tests for my solution with xUnit, and that creates a new project in the same solution, but it ends up in a different folder:
C:\Users\Admin\RiderProjects\MyApp (main solution/project folder)
C:\Users\Admin\RiderProjects\MyApp.Tests (automatically created tests project)

The issue with this is that Git module does not track MyApp.Tests, because it is outside the solution folder. I do not want to have separate repository/tracking for tests, they are and should be part of the main solution and repository. I can merge the folders, but that causes all kinds of namespace clashes, implying that this is not the intended way.
Am I doing something wrong here? How should I set up Rider so that it puts the tests project in the solution folder by default? The Create Unit Test dialog does not allow to specify this as far as I can tell.

@eftshift0 Perhaps, I'm not sure. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, and the tests project is supposed to be outside the solution directory, but Git can/should be somehow setup to include that other project as well, although I can't seem to find how.

Oh, neverming... it is named in there, Comments removed.
